# Unable to Delete/Remove the Custom Timer Job from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-timer-job

am trying to delete the custom timer job I have created in my SP 2013 on-prem.env.
I used the powershell to do the same,but its not getting deleted/removed from the central admin. I tried with restarting the sp timer service and sp admin service and iisreset as well.
refer : [Delete-SPTimer-JOB-link](http://basementjack.com/sharepoint-2/remove-a-stuck-timer-job/)
But still, am able to see the timer job in the timerjob definitions page.

```
  add-pssnapin "microsoft.sharepoint.powershell"


  Get-SPTimerJob | where {$_.name -like "NPD Timer Job"} |fl
  $badjobTake2 = Get-SPTimerJob -ID "55166609-014a-4c0c-bd1b-
  e7cac0585dcd"
  $badjobTake2.Delete()
```

Is there anyway, I can completely remove the timerjob ref from the ContentDB as well? it seems , somewhere the timerjob name is mentioned in Config DB or webappln DB.

note: I have renamed the customer job from a  old name to new name. is this not allowed?  Will this cause an issue when re-deploying onto the same farm?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the job by name instead of ID

```
$jobToDelete = Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.name -eq "customTimerJobName" }
$jobToDelete.Delete()
```

Comment: I already tried this and it didn't work, that's why I went to fetch the ID and tried to delete the same. Any idea , how to remove he reference from content db ? though its not supported, in dev env, I think its OK to delete using the content db id /reference.

Comment: Have you tried to do the same through code i.e. on deactivating the timer job feature delete the timer job. And then check the reference of that timer job.